# Использование union с order by в рекурсивном запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
;with r (childId, parentId, childName, [level], [orderSequence], obj_id1)  
as 
(  
select de.id, de.parent_id, od.name, 0, cast(de.id as varchar(20)), obj_id  
from fstp.dbo.ogpo_dept od
inner join fstp.dbo.dept_employees de On de.obj_id = od.id and de.obj_type = 'dept'  
where obj_id = 75  
union all  
select de.id, de.parent_id, od.name, r.[level]+1, cast(r.orderSequence + '_' + cast(de.id as varchar) as varchar(20)), obj_id  
from fstp.dbo.ogpo_dept od
inner join fstp.dbo.dept_employees de On de.obj_id = od.id and de.obj_type = 'dept' 
inner join r on de.parent_id = r.childId  
)  

select right('         ', ([level]*3)) +childName  
from r  
order by r.orderSequence
```

Запрос работает без `union all`. Хочу добавить строку через `union all`

```
;with r (childId, parentId, childName, [level], [orderSequence], obj_id1)  
as 
(  
select de.id, de.parent_id, od.name, 0, cast(de.id as varchar(20)), obj_id  
from fstp.dbo.ogpo_dept od
inner join fstp.dbo.dept_employees de On de.obj_id = od.id and de.obj_type = 'dept'  
where obj_id = 75  
union all  
select de.id, de.parent_id, od.name, r.[level]+1, cast(r.orderSequence + '_' + cast(de.id as varchar) as varchar(20)), obj_id  
from fstp.dbo.ogpo_dept od
inner join fstp.dbo.dept_employees de On de.obj_id = od.id and de.obj_type = 'dept' 
inner join r on de.parent_id = r.childId  
)  

select 'Все' as childName
union all 
select right('         ', ([level]*3)) +childName  
from r  
order by r.orderSequence
```

Но не получается!

```
The multi-part identifier "r.orderSequence" could not be bound.
```

Как правильно сортировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
;with r (...)
as 
(  
...
),
r2 (num, orderSequence, childName) as
(
    select 1, NULL, 'All'
    union all 
    select 2, orderSequence, right(...) + childName
    from r
)
select childName
from r2
order by num, orderSequence
    ;
```

T.e. заворачиваем `union all` в выражение r2, добавляем дополнительный столбец сортировки `num`, который есть константа 1 для элемента `'Все'`, и 2 для остальных данных, далее сортируем по паре `num, orderSequence`.

Comment: выводить ошибку поле num не найден

Comment: @Zhandos, опечатался. Поправил: `r2 as (num, orderSequence, childName) (...)` -> `r2 (num, orderSequence, childName) as (...)`.